# didReceiveDataOfLength: Problems in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

Im trying to get the amont of data downloaded with this `- (void)download:(NSURLDownload *)theDownload didReceiveDataOfLength:(NSUInteger)length` code from apples website but I need to convert the length to a string. How might I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a string if you need a string:

```
NSString *lengthString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", length];
```

Comment: Thanks but when I run the code I just get the error: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. Any ideas on whats causing this?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a `@` there.  Try again with my edited change.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for your help. It works perfectly. I cant believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do `NSString* stringLength = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%u", length];`?